# DB2 - Unable to post 1MB+ clob data in to table via stored procedure - sqlstate-22001

Tags: sql, db2, mule, db2-400

We are working on a poc with mule and db2.  We are trying to insert 2 MB of data as CLOB datatype in to table via stored procedure, it is working fine if we post clob data less than or equal to 1 MB.  Issue is when we post 1 MB+ data in the host variable of signature in stored procedure then getting out of range error.  Please find below the error details.  Can anyone advise.

Code:-

```
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Configuration"  doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query>
        <![CDATA[{CALL TEST(:testData, :OutParam)}]]>
    </db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="testData" type="CLOB" value="<<2MB of data>>"/>
    <db:out-param name="OutParam" type="BIGINT"/>
</db:stored-procedure>
```

Error

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.9.110 (com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException).
```

Comment: Please post the definition of the stored procedure you're calling.

Comment: What's your table definition? The default CLOB length in Db2 is 1 MB, so if you didn't specify the column length explicitly, it can only hold 1 MB.

Comment: Thanks, it works after including the definition.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Ian's answer as like the below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(IN testData CLOB(2M), OUT OutParam VARCHAR(10))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    declare var1 int=1;
    INSERT INTO TESTING(Payload) values (testData);
    COMMIT;
    set OutParam = var1;
END
```